# Need help in finding the bug (related to pointers to variable on stack)

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

Can some one please tell me what is wrong in my program.
This is basically a program to insert a new node in a binary search tree.

The thing is that my insert function is working correctly and the node is getting inserted
which i am verifying in the main program by the line

```
     cout<<a.left->right->right->data;
```

The output of which is coming correctly i.e 5

but when i try to print a level order traversal of the binary tree some junk value is getting passed in place of the new node and the program is crashing

Can some one please have a look and explain to me what i am doing wrong and how can in the main program the correct value is getting displayed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
#include<array>
#include<stack>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<ctype.h>//isdigit
#include<deque>
#include<queue>
#include<map>
using namespace::std;
struct BST
{
    int data;
    BST *left;
    BST *right;
    BST(int d,struct BST* l,BST *r):data(d) , left(l) ,right(r)
    {
    }
};

void levelOrder(struct BST *root)
{
    struct BST *temp=NULL;
    int count =0;
    deque<struct BST*> dq;
    if(!root)
    {
        return;
    }
    dq.push_back(root);
    count=dq.size();
    while(!dq.empty())
    {
        temp=dq.front();
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        if(temp->left)
        {
            dq.push_back(temp->left);
        }
        if(temp->right)
        {
            dq.push_back(temp->right);
        }
        dq.pop_front();
        if(--count==0)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            count=dq.size();
        }
    }
}
void Insert(struct BST*root,int data)
{
    struct BST temp(data,NULL,NULL);
    if(!root)
    {
        return;
    }
    while(root)
    {
        if((root)->data >data)
        {
            (root)=(root)->left;
            if(!(root)->left)
            {
                (root)->left=&temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            (root)=(root)->right;
            if(!(root)->right)
            {
                (root)->right=&temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    deque<struct BST> dq1,dq2;
    BST e(4,NULL,NULL);
    BST f(3,NULL,NULL);
    BST d(1,&f,NULL);
    //BST g(4,NULL,NULL);
    BST b(2,&d,&e);
    BST c(8,NULL,NULL);
    BST a(6,&b,&c);
    levelOrder(&a);
    Insert(&a,5);
    cout<<a.left->right->right->data;
    cout<<endl;
    levelOrder(&a);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. It will show you where the crash happened, show you the function call stack (and let you traverse it) so you know how you ended up at the place of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you figure out why it happened.

Comment: Oh, and please intend your program! It's **very** hard to read as it is now.

Comment: i have already run it in debug mode program is crashing in level Order function when it is trying to print the data field of the newly inserted Node ,i see some random value in place of 5 ,not sure why because in the main it is showing correctly as 5.

Comment: @Tuxdude thanks for intending the program,i am new here i just pasted my program code after 4 spaces ,not sure what to do to intend it

Comment: Paste the code, highlight it, then hit CTRL+K.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the error is coming after cout<<temp->data<<" "; in levelOrder function a junk value is  getting printed instead of 5 and then the program is crashing giving the message " Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC." i am not sure how to find the bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because you are putting in pointers to a local variable in the tree in the `Insert` function.

When a function returns, all its local variables are no longer "alive", and accessing a pointer to one of those local variables is *undefined behavior*. In fact, the memory those variables once occupied may be overwritten by the next function call, no matter what function you call.

If you want to add a new node, you need to allocate it on the heap using e.g. `new`. However, due to your design of the tree, this will cause a memory leak as you don't free any sub-nodes. In fact, as you use pointers to local variables in the `main` function (that's okay, as the lifetime of those variables are for the duration of `main` which is the whole program) you can't just simply `delete` the pointers Willy-nilly.

Comment: The variable declaration `struct BST temp(data,NULL,NULL);` puts `temp` on the STACK. And when you return that STACK space is reused by something else. Therefore you get corruption.  Learn about the difference between the STACK and the HEAP and be Happy.  Pointer to STACK allocated variable that lives longer than that STACK allocated variable.

Comment: Thanks guys really appreciate your feedback .I guess if i add one more constructor `BST(){}` and a destructor `~BST()` to the `struct BST` and then initialize temp in the level Order function as `BST *temp= new BST()`  and then do `temp->data =data` and `temp->left=temp->right=NULL` then i should be fine or i could do `BST temp= new BST(data,NULL,NULL)`.Have i got it right this time.I just wanted to ask one more thing that since in the main program the correct value was getting displayed,was that only because the memory was not updated by some other value by that time.